# word break legend - eCharts

Tags: legend, line-breaks, echarts, word-break

I want to break the legend text line of a pie chart.

I tried following the documentation of the echarts website but I did not succeed.

```
    legend: {
      orient: 'vertical',
      left: '50%',
      top: 'center',
      data: mydata['data']['categoriestype'],
      textStyle: {
        color: '#CAD3DF',
        fontSize: '14',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        rich: {
          mychart: {
            width: '10'
          }
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question with [ECharts. How to apply width on title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080748/echarts-how-to-apply-width-on-title)

Seems echarts cannot support line break right now.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/9311) in github

> Currently, auto line wrap is not supported. So text with only make
>   sense on text background. We should take into account the
>   implementation of auto line wrap, although it is not easy.

Comment: Thanks... I'm following issue in github

Answer (score 1):

5 years later, I face the same situation. The *legend.textStyle.overflow* with value `"break"` or `"breakAll"` break the line at any cacharacter (event if `"break"` is supposed to break words only) making the reading difficult:
[image: not good]

So I manage to break line in my legend item simply by adding`\n` in the formatter return according to : [How to get newline after the title in echarts line chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393811/how-to-get-newline-after-the-title-in-echarts-line-chart/51790904#51790904)).

Then I've set the *textStyle.width* to 150 and the *itemWidth* to 20 in order to have the 170px set in the grid `"right"` attribute.
I post my workaround there, maybe it will help somebody :

```
grid: {
  right: '170px',
},
legend: {
  type: 'plain',
  orient: 'vertical',
  itemWidth: 20,
  textStyle: {
    width: 150,
    rich: {
      fw600: {
        fontWeight: 600,
      },
    },
  },
  formatter: function (name) {
    const value = 1000;
    return `${name}:\n{fw600|${value}}`;
  }
},
```

Here is the result :

[image: good]